# ListBox Contains Selected ID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, contains

I am having difficulty getting the contains working, what I am trying to do is get the ListBox and see if an ID Number is inside the list of items before I select it so something like this;

```
Session("SavedID") = 3
if ListBoxAccess.Items.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(Session("SavedID"))) Then
        ListBoxAccess.SelectedValue = Session("SavedID")
End If

if ListBoxDenied.Items.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(Session("SavedID"))) Then
        ListBoxDenied.SelectedValue = Session("SavedID")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly thanks both for your help both seem to work OK, however I figured out a shorter answer which I have just used, which doesn't use contains.

```
Session("SavedID") = 3
if ListBoxAccess.Items.FindByValue(Session("SavedID")) IsNot Nothing Then
    ListBoxAccess.SelectedValue = Session("SavedID")
End If

if ListBoxDenied.Items.FindByValue(Session("SavedID")) IsNot Nothing Then
    ListBoxDenied.SelectedValue = Session("SavedID")
End If
```

Tested works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach to check items, and set selected item by value

```
  Dim savedId = Convert.ToInt32(Session("SavedID"))
  For Each item As ListItem In ListBoxAccess.Items
    If item.Value = savedId Then
        item.Selected = True
    End If
  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd expect a missmatch of data types. You can either:

1. Look, whether a listbox contains a ***ListBoxItem***, or
2. Compare ***Value*** of listBoxItem against another value

So either you can create an item to check like:

```
If ListBoxAccess.Items.Contains(ListBoxDenied.Items.Item) Then 
    ...
Else
```

or you have to loop through each item of the listbox and find out yourself, i.e.

```
For Each item in ListBoxAccess.Items
   Dim ValInt as Int32 = CInt(item)
   ...
Next
```